# Generating a matrix using sublists A and B n times

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

I want to write a function that generates a square matrix from sublists. My sublists are

`a = Range[0, x, 0.5]; b = Range[0.25, x + 0.25, 0.5];`

Suppose x=2, then I can manually evaluate {a,b,a,b,a} to generate an 5x5 matrix. I want to make the matrix automatically, of course, but without using a loop.

I've tried different ways to do it, with Nest, Range and Table, but I can't make it work.

Do I absolutely have to use a loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
x = 2;
a = Range[0, x, 0.5];
b = Range[0.25, x + 0.25, 0.5];

PadRight[#, Length@#[[1]], #] & @ {a, b}
```

Could also be written:

```
PadRight[{a,b}, Length@a, {a,b}]
```

---

#### Performance

There is a reason to use the form I proposed over that which Heike gave.  If the first argument of `PadRight` is a packed array, and the padding list is packable (but not necessarily packed) the result will also be packed, and it is produced more quickly than if it were not packed.

```
foo = Range[5]; (* packed array *)

(r1 = PadRight[{},  5*^6, foo];) // RepeatedTiming
(r2 = PadRight[foo, 5*^6, foo];) // RepeatedTiming

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {r1, r2}
Divide @@ ByteCount /@ {r1, r2} // N
```

> ```
> {0.047, Null}
>
> {0.0096, Null}
>
> {False, True}
>
> 2.99999
> ```

So using the list to pad as the seed instead of `{}` can result in five times better speed and three times better memory consumption.

***However*** as [Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) notes this doesn't actually help with the question example.  In either case the vector elements are kept packed but the outer list is not:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

PackedArrayQ /@ PadRight[#,  Length@#[[1]], #] &@{a, b}
PackedArrayQ /@ PadRight[{}, Length@#[[1]], #] &@{a, b}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

So while *in principle* it is better to pad the input list rather than `{}` as *some* cases greatly benefit from it, *this case* does not.

Comment: The version listed in Heike's answer is slightly shorter than (and not too different from) the one given here...

Comment: I ran `AbsoluteTiming[]` on every answer given, and this is the one that was the fastest on my system (with x=35). I felt like I had to choose, and well.. I accepted this answer. The difference between Heike's answer and this one is that Mr.Wizard's is a pure function, a concept that I had not encountered before.

Comment: Unfortunately `{a,b}` is not a packed array. I tried replacing `{a,b}` with `ab` defined as ``ab = Developer`ToPackedArray[{a, b}];``, but ``PadRight[ab, Length@a, ab] // Developer`PackedArrayQ`` is `False`. Is there any way to get the result as a packed array?

Comment: @Karsten It seems that the individual elements (`a`, `b`) are packed but the outer list is not, in either case.  I amended my answer to note this.

Answer (score 13):

Since b is a+0.25, you could use [Outer](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Outer.html) like this:

```
Outer[Plus, PadRight[{}, Length[a], {0, 0.25}], a]
```

You could also create the list of 0s and 0.25s using `Riffle` as in the other answers

(you guys are so fast! It makes iPad use a real handicap :)

Answer (score 12):

You could do something like

```
mat[x_] := Module[{a = Range[0, x, .5], b = Range[.25, x + .25, .5]},
  Riffle[ConstantArray[a, x + 1], {b}]]
```

Then `mat[2]` gives

```
{{0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.}, {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25}, {0., 0.5, 1.,
   1.5, 2.}, {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25}, {0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.}}
```

**Edit**

Perhaps more elegant. This should also work if `x` isn't an integer.

```
mat[x_] := Module[{a = Range[0, x, .5], b = Range[.25, x + .25, .5]},
  PadRight[{}, Floor[2 x + 1], {a, b}]]
```

Comment: What if `x == 2.5`? Or, disregarding the `x` issue,  what if the dimension of `a` is even (I suppose the matrix must be square in all cases)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I assumed that x was an integer.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin the second version should work if `x` isn't an integer.

Comment: Yes, the second one is nice. Although, I somehow think that basing anything on `x` is fragile. I'd use `Length[a]` in place of `Floor[2x+1]`.

Comment: The function is defined as `f[x_Integer]` :)

Comment: Hm... I missed the second one.  `Module` obscured it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you owe me 15 rep ;-)

Comment: Heike I would have deleted my answer but CHM already Accepted it.  I have to leave right now but I think "what to do in this situation" is worthy of a Meta post.  Sorry. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard These things happen. I agree this would be a good thing to discuss on meta.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: you do know that moderators are capable of deleting accepted answers, no?

Comment: @J.M. that seems really inappropriate.  For whatever reason (apparently the pure function is this case) CHM preferred my answer and that is what the check-mark is for.  It was *my mistake* to not read more carefully, not his.

Comment: @Heike I just found two questions of yours I had not yet voted for, and voted.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, as you wish. The situation just doesn't sit well with me, but I leave this to your judgment.

Comment: @Guess I found a good reason for my answer to exist and updated my post.  Hopefully it sits better with you now. (It does for me.)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, yes, it does now. :)

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is this:

```
Riffle[
 ConstantArray[a, Ceiling[Length[a]/2]], 
 ConstantArray[b, Floor[Length[a]/2]]
]
```

Comment: @CHM Actually you could replace the second `ConstantArray[...]` by `{b}` to simplify things a bit.

Comment: `Floor[Length[a]/2]` is more conventionally written as `Quotient[Length[a], 2]`.

Comment: @J.M. Well, conventions change from place to place so it depends who you ask :-)  I use that form as well sometimes, but here what I really needed was the `Ceiling`, and the `Floor` is more symmetrical with that.  Also, I realized the `Floor` part wasn't necessary as a simple `{b}` would do as in @Heike's answer ...

Comment: This is the method I was thinking of, or at least close enough that I don't have to bother putting an answer together.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way without a loop:

```
Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[{a, b}, {Ceiling[Length[a]/2]}], 1], Length[a]]
```

You could also use `Riffle`, I guess.

Comment: @CHM You mean I used loops for this kind of stuff in the book ?! I thought better of myself.

Comment: Quite the opposite - you suggest NOT to use loops, and make use of Mathematica's functional programming capabilities instead. As I'm learning to use Mathematica, I'd rather learn to code efficiently.

Comment: @CHM Well, that's a relief.  I started thinking I did use loops, which would mean that I wasn't in the right mind when writing that part.

Comment: @CHM In fact, today is an anniversary - it is exactly 3 years that I released the book to the general audience (it was written one year prior to that, but I did not have a web version).

Comment: Congratulations on being first to 5000! :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! That wouldn't happen this soon without your help :)

Comment: I probably owe you some more votes too.  I have bookmarked questions I need to revisit and a number of these I held myself from voting on until I understood all the answers better.  Actually I am not using bookmarks but Favorite Questions therefore you can see the list yourself (though it is mixed with actual favorite questions as well at this point).

Answer (score 7):

I find using `Band` in a `SparseArray` interesting.

```
mat[x_] :=
 Block[{a = Range[0, x, .5],
   b = Range[.25, x + .25, .5], ln},
   ln = Length[a];
   SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {ln, ln}] -> {a, b}, {ln, ln}]
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You've gotten several good answers already. Another way of doing it is to use `MapIndexed` as:

```
MapIndexed[If[EvenQ@First@#2, b, a] &, a];
```

This should be reasonably fast, but certainly not as fast as the `PadRight` answer. In the same vein, you can use related conditional constructs, `Switch` and `Which` as:

```
 MapIndexed[Switch[EvenQ@First@#2, True, b, False, a] &, a]; 
 MapIndexed[Which[Mod[#2, 2] == {1}, a, Mod[#2, 2] == {0}, b] &, a];
```

Answer (score 5):

Or ...

Using `ConstantArray`:

```
 mat0 := Most@Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
 ({#, .25 + #} & /@ ConstantArray[#, Ceiling[(Length@#)/2]]&@
 Range[0, #, .5] &) ;
 mat0@2.2
 (* gives *)
```

> {{0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.}, {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25}, {0., 0.5, 1.,
>      1.5, 2.}, {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25}, {0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 
>     2.}}

Using `Table`:

```
 mat2:=Most@Flatten[#, 1] & /@ (Transpose /@ 
  Table[{#, .25 + #} & /@ #, {Ceiling[(Length@#1)/2]}] &@ Range[0, #, .5] &)
```

Using `NestList`:

```
 mat3:=Most@Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
(NestList[Join, {#1, #2}, Floor[(Length@#1)/2]] & @@ {#, .25 + #} &
 @Range[0, #, .5] &)
```

Using `Table` again (less cluttered and more general):

```
 mat4:= Table[{#2, #1}[[1 + Mod[i, 2]]], {i, #3}] &;
 mat5 := Table[{#1, #2}[[1 + Mod[i, 2]]], {i, 0, #3 - 1}] &;
 mat4[{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, 5]
 (* and  *)
 mat5[{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, 5]
 (* both give *)
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {a, b, c, d}}
> ```

Comment: Nice. Clearly, my methods using Table and Nest(List) weren't as involved as yours, but they didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Let me join. This variant avoids explicit `a` and `b` initialization.

```
x = 2; n = 2 x + 1;
SparseArray[{
   {i_, j_} /; OddQ@i -> 0.5 (j - 1),
   {i_, j_} /; EvenQ@i -> 0.5 j - 0.25},
{n, n}] // Normal

(* ==>
    {{0, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.}, 
     {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25}, 
     {0, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.},
     {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25},
     {0, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2.}} *)
```