# Generate cyclic list from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list (for example, `{3, 5}`) I would like to make a function `genCyclic[n_, list_]` which generates a cyclic patterns of list with length `n`, such that `genCyclic[5, {3, 5}]` returns `{3, 5, 3, 5, 3}` or `genCyclic[1, {3, 5}]` returns `{3}`.

My current solution is to use `ConstantArray` to generate the full cycle parts (`{3, 5, 3, 5}` in the first example) and append the remaining part (`{3}`) and then `Flatten` them. I have to say my method seems too ugly.

In my old memory, which is frequently wrong, though, I thought there was a built-in function with this functionality. After spending some time trying to find such a function and failing, I ended up here.

No matter whether there is a built-in function or not, what is the most natural way to implement `genCyclic`?

Comment: Closely related: [(1633)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1633/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is something quite strightforward:

```
 genCyclic[n_, list_] := PadRight[{}, n, list]
```

Comment: I've always done `PadRight[list, n, list]`, so I guess I've been writing more code than I needed to. +1

Comment: @rcollyer in case of PadRight[#,n,#]& you can gain one character over {} :)

Comment: truthfully, I usually end up using that form, or using single letter variable names, like `PadRight[l, n, l]`, so that I get the benefits without dealing with the pain.

Comment: @rcollyer Your form is superior because the first element of `PadRight` needs to be packed if possible, and `{}` is not packable.  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1639/121) for example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard as long as my method is correct somehow. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
gcF = PadRight[#2, #, #2] &;
gcF[5, {3, 5}]
(* {3, 5, 3, 5, 3} *)
```

You can also use `"Periodic"` for the third argument of `PadRight` that specifies the *padding*:

```
gcF1 = PadRight[#2, #, "Periodic"] &;
```

As far as I know, this form of `PadRight` (and `PadLeft`) is not documented.

Few more alternatives using `ArrayPad`, `Part` or `ArrayReshape`:

```
gcF2 = ArrayPad[#2, {0, # - Length@#2}, "Periodic"] &;
gcF3 = #2[[Mod[Range@#, Length@#2, 1]]] &;
gcF4 = ArrayReshape[#2, {#1}, #2] &;
gcF5 = ArrayReshape[#2, {#1}, "Periodic"] &;
```

Comment: Weird, I've never seen `ArrayPad` before, and it's not a new function. +1

Comment: @rcollyer You are not participating here as often as you should then!

Comment: @Kuba obviously.

Comment: Thank you @rcollyer for the vote. It has a few nice built-in paddings.