# Cyclic Take function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Is there some direct and simple "cyclic Take", sometimes also known as "overtake" in *Mathematica*. That is, if the take specification runs out of elements, it just cycles back to the beginning (as many times as necessary).

For example, if the functions were named `OverTake`, then:

```
OverTake[{1, 2}, 5]
(* {1, 2, 1, 2, 1} *)
```

(This would be a direct analog of the take functions in the array-processing languages APL and J.)

I can clumsily code a function to do that, but I was hoping for a simple use of something built in.

Comment: Maybe `PadRight[{}, 5, {1, 2}]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs That's brilliant! It also naturally handles the "normal" `Take` usage when requesting fewer elements than the length of the list. Please post it as an answer!

Comment: I'm waiting for @Szabolcs to post his comment as answer, since that's the one I'd like to mark (as the simplest).

Comment: I guess you can accept kglr's :)

Comment: related/duplicate q/a: [Generate cyclic list from a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76246/125)?

Comment: Then @Kuba's answer at the related/duplicate you cite ought to be the accepted answer! Any way to do that? (I'm not trying to be stinting in awarding credit to anybody!)

Comment: murray, I think this q/a can be closed as duplicate of the linked q/a. I will delete my answer for it also appears in that q/a. But I don't know how to deal with new answers (like eldo's) that appear only in the current q/a -- perhaps @eldo can post his answer there but that would mean losing the votes when this q/a is eventually deleted as duplicate.

Comment: But it would be nice to preserve using the `"Periodic"` argument to `PadRight`. It will be once this is closed, right?

Comment: murray, my answer in the linked q/a includes `PadRight[...,"Periodic"]`.

Comment: @kglr I'd like to join murray in asking you to consider undeleting your answer. Although you do reference using `"Periodic"` with `PadRight` in the other answer, I don't see why it shouldn't be preserved here as well.

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for the suggestion. I undeleted the answer.

Comment: I don't mind preserving those answers, but I'd still close it as duplicate.

Comment: Related: [(1633)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1633/121)

Answer (score 29):

A variation on Szabolcs's suggestion:

```
overTake = PadRight[##, "Periodic"] &;
overTake[{1, 2}, 5]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}

Comment: Where did you lean about the `"Periodic"` argument to `PadRight`? I'm not seeing it at doc page `ref/PadRight`.

Comment: See `Details` for `ArrayPad`

Comment: @murray, afaik, the fact that `PadRight` and `PadLeft` work with a third argument just like `ArrayPad` is  undocumented. I found out by pure luck -- wishing `PadRight` worked like `ArrayPad`, tried it and saw it worked:)

Answer (score 14):

```
Catenate @ Partition[{1, 2}, 5, 5, 1]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}

```
OverTake[list_, n_] /; Length @ list >= n := Take[list, n]

OverTake[list_, n_] /; Length @ list < n := Catenate @ Partition[list, n, n, 1]

OverTake[Range @ 5, 6]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}

```
OverTake[Range @ 5, 4]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

**Update**

Faster than solutions with `PadRight` and `Partition`

```
l = 2;
n = 5;
list = Range @ l;

Flatten@ConstantArray[list, IntegerPart[n/l]]~Join~list[[;; Mod[n, l]]]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}

Also works for `n < l`

Comment: See update -----

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for addressing that point! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons, let me mention the `CycleValues` function that originates before v6, and can be found in several standard packages. I copy the one from `Packages\BarCharts\Charts.m` with its description by the dev who included. (If you check however `StatisticalPlots.m`, it already uses the `PadRight` version.) Note, that it was meant to handle non-list arguments as well.

```
(* The following is a useful internal utility function to be
used when you have a list of values that need to be cycled to
some length (as PlotStyle works in assigning styles to lines
in a plot).  The list is the list of values to be cycled, the
integer is the number of elements you want in the final list. *)

CycleValues[{},_] := {}
CycleValues[list_List, n_Integer] := Module[{hold = list},
        While[Length[hold] < n,hold = Join[hold,hold]];
        Take[hold,n] /. None -> {}
    ]
CycleValues[item_,n_] := CycleValues[{item}, n];


CycleValues[0, 5]        (* ==> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
CycleValues[{1, 2}, 5]   (* ==> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1} *)
```

Comment: I wonder where that `None` could come from...?

Comment: I dont' know but better skip that ;) `CycleValues[None, 5]`