# Repeating a list k times

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list, say $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and I would like to repeat this list k times to obtain a list of $4k$ elements that looks like $\{1,2,3,4,1,2,..,1,2,3,4\}$.

I was hoping something like `li * k` would do this but unfortunately that's pointwise multiplication. What's the right operator that would do something like this for me?

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};

a = Flatten @ Table[list, 4]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
b = Round @ Flatten @ ReplicateLayer[4, 1] @ list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
c = Round @ Flatten @ ReplicateLayer[4, 2] @ list
```

{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}

`ReplicateLayer` packs, `Table` doesn't:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, b, c}
```

{False, True, True}

[what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)

One can easily chain layers:

```
rep = Round @* ReplicateLayer[2,1] @* Flatten @* ReplicateLayer[2, 1];

rep @ list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### ***"I was hoping something like li * k would do this ..."***

#### [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) + [`Splice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html)

```
ClearAll[Star]

Star[l_, k_] := ConstantArray[Splice @ l, k]

{1, 2, 3, 4}⋆3
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead of `ConstantArray` to get the same result.

#### [`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html)

```
ClearAll[Diamond]

Diamond[l_List, k_Integer] := PadRight[l, k Length@l, l]

{1, 2, 3, 4}⋄3
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

**Note:** You can use any of the [Operators without Built-in Meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#41) instead of `\[Star]` and `\[Diamond]`.

**Note:**  Although still undocumented, `PadRight[l, k Length@l, "Periodic"]` also works.

Comment: How does one discover hidden "options" like "Periodic"? Also, hopefully no one ever needs to use "Periodic" as their padding :) . I usually use the list itself as padding `PadRight[list, length, list]`.

Comment: @lericr, _discovered_ `"Periodic"` in the third argument of `PadRight/PadLeft` by the _method_ of  [wishful thinking + luck](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99190/125):) I agree `PadRight[list, length, list]` is _woker_.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can get 10 ways to do this. Just to the add to the list of fun ways to do this using fun function names:

```
[l0_, k_] := Nest[Join[#, l0] &, {}, k]

[Range@4, 3]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SubstitutionSystem[MapApply[Rule]@Partition[Range[#1],
  2,1,1],1,(#1 #2)-1]&[4,3]//Flatten

(* {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4} *)


SubstitutionSystem[MapApply[Rule]@Partition[Range[#1],
  2,1,1],1,(#1 #2)-1]&[10,3]//Flatten

(* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `ConstantArray` and `Cases`:

```
f[lst_, k_] := Cases[ConstantArray[lst, k], x_ :> Sequence @@ x]

f[list, 4]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
k = 4;
```

````
ArrayReshape[list, {Length[list] k}, list]

 (* {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4} *)

Flatten@Array[list &, k]

 (* {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```
````